# How to set dynamic responsive divs with only CSS (no javascript)?

Tags: html, css

Basically what I want is my main div to stretch out as much it needs based on the height of the categories div, or the content (whichever is higher); and my product pictures. [This is the ominous site](http://verychard.com/responsive/)

My issues are the following:

- The content div and the categories div are both children of the main div, however the pictures of the products float out of it. Eventually on zooming it floats out to the right as well.
- So if I set the #main width to a percent the zooming gets very silly, (zooming out doesn't make the picture smaller, nor the divs or the logo, only the the buttons in categories.
  But if I set to a constant, then it's nice, but again how will it be responsive?
- Why is the border of the categories isn't in the right place? (in vertical)
- In responsive mobile view the pictures are again on top of everything and there is a scroll bar, when I disabled zooming and it should show full screen. I must be missing something vital here. Also the footer is in the middle of everything and there is an extra black part between the header and the categories, yet there is no margin or padding in any of those elements. [See it here](http://verychard.com/responsive/stackq/achieve.png)

Thanks in advance!

ps.: I've tried many things starting from varying the heights, widths, playing with margins, overflows, but couldn't find a clue how to do it properly.
pps: I've inserted the code here so you don't have to open the source on the above site, for faster check.

```css
body {
  background-color: #161718;
  background-image: url('../pictures/mdbg.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(230, 16, 16, 1) 1%, rgba(136, 7, 8, 1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #1d1e20;
  border-right: 3px solid #880708;
  border-left: 3px solid #880708;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #880708;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#logo {
  margin: 20%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40%;
}
#categories {
  width: 15%;
  border-right: 3px solid #880708;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  font: 12px Verdana;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul#categories a {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(193, 32, 38, 1) 1%, rgba(104, 12, 13, 1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 80%;
}
#content {
  float: right;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#content img {
  width: 26%;
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  left: 25%;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 3px solid #880708;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
/* Laptop/Tablet (1366px) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #main {
    width: 1000px;
  }
  footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #categories {
    width: 15%;
  }
  #content {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
/* Laptop/Tablet (1024px) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #main {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
  footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #categories {
    width: 20%;
  }
  #content {
    width: 80%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 38%;
  }
}
/* Tablet Portrait (768px) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  body {
    background-image: none;
  }
  #main {
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
  }
  footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #logo {
    display: none;
  }
  #categories {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
  }
  ul#categories a {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2.6em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 15%;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  #content img {
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    left: 0%;
  }
}
/* Phone Landscape (480px) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .box {
    float: left;
  }
  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
  }
  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #categories {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Phone Portrait (320px) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .box {
    float: left;
  }
  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
  }
  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #categories {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.verychard.com/responsive/styles/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <!--320 mobile devices cant zoom-->
  <title>Webshop</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header></header>

  <div id="main">


    <ul id="categories">
      <img id="logo" src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/kecske.png" />
      <li><a>Motherboard</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Processor</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Memory</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>FSP</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Whatever</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Monitor</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Motherboard</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Processor</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Memory</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>FSP</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Whatever</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Monitor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content">
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
      <img src="http://www.verychard.com/responsive/termek.png" alt="picture" />
    </div>


    <footer>All rights reserved Kecske PC 2015</footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is partially unclear, provide us some code. Thanks.

Comment: use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries this.  you can be as tedious to adjust every height width as you like

Comment: usually, set a fixed width for large screen and 100% width for small screen.  but that is optional.

Comment: @Milan You can check by the source code of the site I've provided so you see what I mean, but I can paste the code here, it's really not much

Comment: Your css is trying to control too much of the positioning on the page, the absolute and relative positioning of each element is somewhat overkill and because of that it's causing a lot of issues when the page is a different resolution from what you originally coded it as. Where things are floating and what stays contained in which element become complicated. Instead of `height: 100%` try using a clearfix, float your children elements, and let the browser do the heavy lifting with the fluid boxes instead. That way you can minimize the media query styles and only change what needs to be changed.

Comment: wlin I use them as you can see, and can't get to work as I would like
@DaveGoten thanks, will look into it :o :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a generally accepted version of clearfix, and removed a lot of positioning. The big thing is your widths were 15% + 85% = 100% + 3px for border, so it forced the element down to the next line, that's why I suspect you needed the absolute positioning to make it stay where you want it, so now it's 15% and 75%. It's not prefect but it's a start I hope.

```
body {
  background-color:#161718;
  background-image:url('../pictures/mdbg.png');
  background-position:center; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

header{
  width:100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(230, 16, 16, 1) 1%, rgba(136, 7, 8, 1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#main{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #1d1e20;
  border: 3px solid #880708;
  border-top: 0px none transparent;
  min-height: 200px;
  position:relative;
}

#logo{
  margin: 20%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 40%;
}

#categories{
  width: 15%;
  border-right: 3px solid #880708;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  font: 12px Verdana;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
}


ul#categories a {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(193, 32, 38, 1) 1%, rgba(104, 12, 13, 1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 80%;   
}

#content{
  float:right;
  width:75%; /* 100% - 15% - 3px > 85% so mind the gap */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content img{
  width: 26%;
}

footer {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  border-top: 3px solid #880708;
  bottom: 0;
}



/* Laptop/Tablet (1366px) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  header {  }
  #main { width: 1000px; }
  footer {  }
  #categories {  }
  #content {  }
}

/* Laptop/Tablet (1024px) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  header { }
  #main { width: 100%; border:none;}
  footer {  }
  #categories { width: 20%; }
  #content { width: 70%; }
}

/* Tablet Portrait (768px) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {

  header { height: 10%; padding: 0px;}
  body {background-image:none;}
  #main {  border:0px; width: 100%; min-width: 200px;}
  footer { }
  #logo {display:none;}
  #categories { width: 100%; border:0px;}
  ul#categories a { width:100%; font-size:2.6em; margin: 0 auto; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom: 10px; display: inline-block;}
  #content {width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; left: 15%; overflow:scroll; padding-top: 15px;}
  #content img{width: 80%;}

}

/* Phone Landscape (480px) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .box { float: left; }
  header {height: 40px;}
  main { width: 100%; }
  footer { }
  #categories { width: 100%; }
  #content { width: 100%; }
}

/* Phone Portrait (320px) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .box { float: left; }
  header { height: 40px;}
  main { width: 100%; }
  footer {  }
  #categories { width: 100%;}
  #content { width: 100%; }
}
```

With some small changes to the html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"> <!--320 mobile devices cant zoom-->
    <title>Webshop</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header></header>

    <div id="main" class="clearfix">


      <ul id="categories">
        <img id="logo" src="kecske.png">
        <li><a>Motherboard</a></li>
        <li><a>Processor</a></li>
        <li><a>Memory</a></li>
        <li><a>FSP</a></li>
        <li><a>Whatever</a></li>
        <li><a>Monitor</a></li>
        <li><a>Motherboard</a></li>
        <li><a>Processor</a></li>
        <li><a>Memory</a></li>
        <li><a>FSP</a></li>
        <li><a>Whatever</a></li>
        <li><a>Monitor</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="content">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">
        <img src="termek.png" alt="picture">

      </div>


      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <footer>All rights reserved Kecske PC 2015</footer>
    </div>


    <style>.tb_button {padding:1px;cursor:pointer;border-right: 1px solid #8b8b8b;border-left: 1px solid #FFF;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}.tb_button.hover {borer:2px outset #def; background-color: #f8f8f8 !important;}.ws_toolbar {z-index:100000} .ws_toolbar .ws_tb_btn {cursor:pointer;border:1px solid #555;padding:3px}   .tb_highlight{background-color:yellow} .tb_hide {visibility:hidden} .ws_toolbar img {padding:2px;margin:0px}</style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Fixed some formatting (don't copy form console, it's bad for your OCD).

Comment: Pretty decent! Thanks for the heads up on the border thingy, that really is illogical :) However I can't figure out what button do you style in the html's last rows. And unfortunately my div still not stretch to fit the contents (categories+content). It can be seen on zooming, they overlay the parent div. If you provided a solution for that, I would be very happy.
And you also solved my problem with the borders, seems really logical now how you just clear the top of the main, but I don't know what you've done for the misplacement of the border of the menu :P

Comment: I've edited now the code and after deleting "height" from #content, they don't overlap anymore! :) Thanks for the help again <3